printing colored hyperlinks in solid black
I have written the following.
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\label{firstLabel}
\lipsum
\label{secondLabel}
\lipsum
\par See page~\pageref{firstLabel}.
\par See page~\pageref{secondLabel}.
\end{document} 

The two pageref appear in red in the generated PDF, which is fine.  My goal is that when I print a hard copy, they should appear in solid, rather than some fainter, black.  However, when, within Adobe, I print my PDF to a new PDF using the black-and-white option, they yet appear red in the new PDF so that the hard copy will surely produce them in a faint black.  Is this a LaTeX problem or an Adobe problem?

when I switch the layers in adobe reader the print preview shows the link in black.

Thanks so much.  I do not have the version of Adobe that would enable me to see this.  But I believe you.  So this is good.
